# is it safe to port forward SQL server to whitelisted IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql, port-forwarding

I need to access an SQL server behind a router from an AWS EC2 instance.
Is it reasonably safe to open a port on the router if I am white listing the IP of the EC2 instance?

If there is a best practice for this, or if anyone knows of a procedure for this any references are welcome!

SQL server OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 on domain controlled network
SQL Server version: 2008 R2 SP3

AWS EC2 instance OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Intention: Access SQL with sequelize on an expressjs based web server

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing and somewhat imprecise. What does port forwarding have to do with this? If you simply want to give an EC2 instance to a database on-premise, yes that can be done securely, either using IP whitelisting and user / password or even better with a VPN.

Comment: This is essentially what I've set up. After testing the whitelisting from different IP's Im' fairly confident that approach will suffice. A VPN would be overkill on the budget for this project, and the data is not something anybody would have a reason to go after. I'm mostly concerned about random, malicious low effort attacks. I appreciate your speedy response!

Comment: @Tim if you add this as an answer I will likely accept it. Gonna leave it open for a few days to see what input anyone else may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing and somewhat imprecise. What does port forwarding have to do with this?

If you simply want to give an EC2 instance to a database on-premise, yes that can be done securely, either using IP whitelisting and user / password or even better with a VPN.

The database has a username and password, which is probably adequate protection. Combine that with IP whitelisting and it's probably good protection. However, it still allows anyone who can fake the source IP to get access to the instance, and if the database software has any bugs it leaves you vulnerable.

Generally a VPN is recommended. That gives you another line of protection, and effectively extends your data center into AWS. Large companies often put AWS onto an internal IP range, but so long as you can route to it that doesn't really matter. You can then whitelist only your internal IP ranges. The three protections would make more more comfortable - VPN, IP whitelisting, and user / password.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to ask this question, no.  I dont use MSSQL, but I'm well versed in other databases and networking. It is, of-course doable, but requires careful implementation.

The first issue is that by exposing the database port to the Internet you are opening it up to attack, both in terms of accessing it and DoS.  You can mitigate this risk with appropriate firewalling.

The second issue is one of security. (From what I've read) SQL by default does not encrypt traffic. You would want to either set up a VPN or enable TLS and ensure appropriate trust or, ideally, both. If you dont do this, third parties can see data, and possibly change data using a MITM attack.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up concerning encryption! I will certainly keep that in mind.